# Appending html code through angularJS for chat-bot But not working same code

Tags: angularjs, chatbot

I am displaying calendar through angular. It works perfectly when I use the code below code. 
But when I append the same code on a chat-bot dialog at runtime, it doesn't work anymore. The date-picker is not showing anymore.

[image: It is displaying calendar on click as expected]

[image: It is not displaying calendar using same code(appended code)]

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" 
      class="form-control text-box datetimepicker ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-date" 
      name="txtIndividualDeparture" 
      placeholder="Departure" 
      uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
      ng-model="txtIndividualDeparture" 
      is-open="Departure.opened" 
      datepicker-options="departuredateOptions" 
      show-button-bar="false" 
      ng-required="true" 
      close-text="" 
      alt-input-formats="travel.altInputFormats" 
      ng-click="Departure.opened = true" 
      ng-change="setReturnMinDateIndividual()" 
      required="required">
    <div uib-datepicker-popup-wrap="" 
      ng-model="date" 
      ng-change="dateSelection(date)" 
      template-url="uib/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html" 
      class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty">
      <!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="Departure.opened = true"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When DOM that contains AngularJS directives is added by a 3rd party library, often the directives are not linked properly to the AngularJS framework model because the 3rd party library is not aware of AngularJS.

Comment: You might need to grab the scope of the element you're appending to and trigger a digest e.g. `angular.element(document.querySelector('.container-element')).scope().$apply();` or have a play with `$compile`